# Default hyphenation / langid field in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages

I want to include a lot of bibliography entries in various languages. The great majority are in english and only a handful is in another language. I have no `language`, `langid` or `hyphenation` fields, to use different language per entry. I can manualy add the `langid` filed to the non-english entries. Is there a way to set `langid={english}` by default for every entry that it is not set?

Comment: I would have thought entries without a `langid` fall back to the document language. Wouldn't that be enough for your purposes?

Comment: @moewe, that's exaclty the problem, the document language is greek, I thus see anything without `langid` field in greek!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The description of the `autolang` option on p. 48 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) says

> [The `autolang`] option controls which `babel` language environment is used if the `babel`/`polyglossia` package is loaded and a bibliography entry includes a `langid` field (see § 2.2.3). Note that Biblatex automatically adjusts to the main document language if `babel`/`polyglossia` is loaded. In multilingual documents, it will also continually adjust to the current language as far as citations and the default language of the bibliography is concerned. This option is for switching languages on a per-entry basis within the bibliography.

So if no `langid` field is provided `biblatex` falls back to the current language. Consider the following MWE where `british` is the document language and `uthor` does not come with a `langid` field, while `torin` has `ngerman`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,autolang=other]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{uthor,
  author    = {Anne Uthor},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {An English Title},
  booktitle = {Collection},
  editor    = {Eddie Tor},
}
@incollection{torin,
  author     = {Anne U. Torin},
  year       = {2002},
  title      = {Ein deutscher Titel},
  booktitle  = {Sammelband},
  editor     = {Heinz E. Rausgeber},
  langid     = {ngerman},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`torin` is set in German, while `uthor` remains in (British) English.

[image: example output]

---

If you insist on setting the `langid` field for entries that do not yet have it, use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue={english}]
    }
  }
}
```

since this mapping does not overwrite fields, only those entries without a `langid` get `english` now.

Comment: Thank you! As I commented to the main question, the document's language is not english... I tried your last solution, which works in many cases, but not all of them! I still try to figure out the common point of the non-working entries/files.

Comment: After deleting all auxilliary files, it worked perfectly!