# Error `IsDOIGray' with bibliography style langsci-unified, compilation with xelatex

Tags: biblatex

I really need help if possible. I am struggling with an error I do not how to fix. After tracking it, it points to the langsci-unified style I am using since with other bibliography styles (for instance, apa), the document prints fine. The error is always related to something like **IsDOIGray** like this one : **! Undefined control sequence.
\blx@theformat #1->{\color
{lsDOIGray}DOI\addcolon \space \ifhyperref {\href...
l.17**  or **! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `lsDOIGray'**.

Please help me to fix it if possible. I am compiling with Xelatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[style=langsci-unified, natbib]{biblatex}
\makeatletter

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{Thompson1996}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `langsci-unified`, which is distributed on CTAN as part of the [`langsci` bundle](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/langsci), is assumed to be used together with the `langscibook` document class.

If you use the style with a different class, you need to make sure you load `xcolor` and supply a suitable colour definition for `lsDOIGray`. The definition in the following is taken from `langscibook.cls`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=langsci-unified, natbib]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lsDOIGray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.45}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma & Ulf Ryde. 1998. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19(4). 377–395. DOI: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

It is pretty unusual for a bibliography style to tacitly assume you are using a specific class, so you may want to contact the style developer about this at https://github.com/langsci/langscibook/issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. I think that is what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a workaround. The Trick may be, to not use the `langsci-class`, but your usual document class (e.g. `scrartcl`) and to paste a whole lot of code into the preamble, in order to define the langsci-style right in the document. For instance, I could not even implement `style=langsci-unified`, it was treated as if there was no such style.

Stefan Müller proposes to simply paste the following code into the preamble and it works fine for me (source: [https://hpsg.hu-berlin.de/~stefan/Lehre/unified-biblatex.sty](https://hpsg.hu-berlin.de/%7Estefan/Lehre/hausarbeiten.html)):

```
\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    style=langsci-unified,
    citestyle=langsci-unified,
    datamodel=langsci,   % add authauthor and autheditor as possible fields to
                                % bibtex entries
    useprefix = true, %sort von, van, de where they should appear
    %refsection=chapter,
    maxbibnames=99,
    mincrossrefs=99,
    maxcitenames=2,
        uniquename=false,
    isbn=false,
    doi=true,
    url=true,
    eprint=false,
        useprefix=true,
    backend=biber,
    indexing=cite,
        autolang=hyphen,
%        sorting=ydnt,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lsDOIGray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.45}


% if no langid is set, it is English:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279302
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue={english}]
    }
  }
}

% If the user provided a shortauthor in the bibtex entry, we use the authentic author (as with the
% authorindex package) if it is defined, otherwise we use the author.
% This gets F/T as shorthand right and puts the guys in the index.

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shortauthor} % If biblatex uses shortauthor as the label of a bibitem
      {\ifnameundef{authauthor}                     % we check whether there is something in authauthor
        {\indexnames{author}}                       % if not, we use author
        {\indexnames{authauthor}}}                  % if yes, we use authauthor
      {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{author}    % if biblatex uses author we similarly test for
                                                    % authauthor and use this field
        {\ifnameundef{authauthor}% if defined use authauthor
          {\indexnames{author}}
          {\indexnames{authauthor}}} % if defined use this field
        {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shorteditor} % same for editor
          {\ifnameundef{autheditor}
            {\indexnames{editor}}
            {\indexnames{autheditor}}}
          {\indexnames{labelname}}}}}               % as a fallback we index on whatever biblatex used.
    {}}


%\bibliography{bib-abbr,biblio}

%\usepackage{fixcitep}


% cite somebodys work
\let\citew=\citet


%\usepackage{biblatex-series-number-checks}
```

ATTENTION: If you use `\addbibresource`, you **have to** put it right after the line `]{biblatex}` and before `\usepackage{xcolor}`.